# Symfony 4 translation resources best practice

Tags: symfony, translation

According to the symfony docs, in order for the translation service to work, you need to create a resource with one of the known valid extension for this thing, resulting in a format like: domain.locale.extension . Symfony code looks for a 'messages' domain as default and if you want to organize those translation better, you can specify the new domain in the third argument of the function trans().
And here is where i'm a bit confused.I read somewhere(can't remember where) that is a better practice to divide your translation catalog in multiple files like

- labels.en.xlf
- labels.ro.xlf
- options.en.xlf
- options.ro.xlf
- messages.en.xlf
- messages.ro.xlf

I'm creating a file for each purpose so it can be organized, but here's the problem... for now i have only 2 languages, further i'm planning on adding all of them.Also,for now i got only 3 domains, but further i will surely add more.
This will result in tons on files, but isn't that a bit nasty for performance?
I mean, it may be a better practice to organize it in multiple files but symfony will have to load all of those files which will affect the performance for sure, but if i'll keep just the 'messages' domain and add every translation inside it wouldn't be better?
Another thing is the syntax of the trans() function.Is much better to call it like this:

```
$translator->trans('translation.id');
```

than this:

```
$translator->trans('translation.id', array(), 'theNewDomain');
```

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the files are only loaded once via cache:warmup see var/cache/{env}/translations/

then you only have one catalog per locale.

Comment: so there is no down side from the multiple files approach, performance-wise... though it really bothers me that i have to specify 3 arguments instead of one each time i wanna translate something

Comment: depending where you use the translation. for example if you use twig you can define the translation domain once for the whole template `{% trans_default_domain 'whatever' %}` in forms you can set it in the defaults `'translation_domain' => 'whatever'` - in a service/controller you could use a wrapper which sets the domain automaticly...